# Chat process in XMPP Openfire server using Android application

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack

I’m using Openfire XMPP server for a android chat application. I can connect and login to the server using my app.

Now I want to know how to send friend request and accept friend request in this chat application.

I can fetch all the user from server but I want to know the process of starting a chat.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you are using Smack as an xmpp sdk for you android application?

Comment: yes smack api at android end @Mark

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android ADD FRIEND using Smack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812855/android-add-friend-using-smack)

Answer (score 2):

The processes are a bit more complex than it looks to add/accept friend requests you need to do some juggling with `presence` and and `roster iq` stanzas.

I'll try to give you an indication about what stanzas are sent/received using contacts operations below.

```
1. Add contact
    To add a contact you need to send a `subscribe` stanza. 
    <presence xmlns="jabber:client" to="you@app.com/123" id="9VO8j-1" type="subscribe" from="me@app.com/1234" />
    1.1. Request accepted
        When adding a contact and the other app "accepts the request" you receive two stanzas:
            1. <presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="you@app.com/123" id="9VO8j-1" type="subscribed" to="me@app.com/1234" />
            2. <presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="you@app.com/123" id="9VO8j-2" type="subscribe" to="me@app.com/1234" />
            3. <presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="me@app.com/1234" id="9VO8j-3" type="subscribed" to="you@app.com/123" />

    1.2. Request Denied
        When the request is denied you receive an "UNSUBSCRIBED" stanza.
            Example: <presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="you@app.com/123" id="9VO8j-1" type="unsubscribed" to="me@app.com/1234" />

2. Accept contact request
    1. <presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="me@app.com/1234" id="9VO8j-1" type="subscribed" to="you@app.com/123" />
    2. <presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="me@app.com/1234" id="9VO8j-2" type="subscribe" to="you@app.com/123" />

3. Deny contact request
    <presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="me@app.com/1234" id="9VO8j-1" type="unsubscribed" to="you@app.com/123" />

4. Remove contact
    When you "Delete" a contact you should be in fact be "deleting" it locally in your app and from the roster. 
    This is done by sending two stanzas:
        1. <presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="me@app.com/1234" id="9VO8j-3" type="unsubscribe" to="you@app.com/123"/>
        2. <iq from='me@app.com/1234' id='ah382g67' to='you@app.com/123' type='set'>
             <query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster' ver='ver34'>
               <item jid='you@app.com/123' subscription='remove'/>
             </query>
            </iq>
```

***Note:*** The use-cases described above do not include all the ***iq:roster*** stanzas associated to the `presence` stanzas. These are sent automatically by the server whenever a contact changes the `subscription` and `ask` types.

For a better understanding of how the these workflows work in details I suggest you read the latest RFC (implemented by your server). You can find it on the [office site](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html).

See section ***3. Managing the roster***.

Comment: Forgot to mention. This a generic answer, you can easily adapt it to `smack` and send/process the needed stanzas.